# How to extend class from library when there's an interface involved?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I have a library that provides class `Foo`. I extend `Foo` with some of my own member functions in class `FooExtended`. In order to use `FooExtended` in my unit tests I must make it mockable, therefore I create an interface `IFoo` and this is the type I use all throughout my codebase. Then I created two implementations of the interface:

- Class `FooMock` - used for unit tests.
- Class `FooWrapper` - used in the actual program. Mainly it's a wrapper for `FooExtended`, an instance of which it stores as a member.

**Problem:** The problem is with the `FooWrapper`. I don't know how to utilise the factory `Lib::create_foo()` to create `Foo` as the library wants, but also have the `my_added_function()` which I added in `FooExtended`. The `dynamic_cast` fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

// What's in this namespace is in a 3rd party lib that I cannot change.
namespace Lib {

class Foo {
  public:
    virtual ~Foo() {};

    int lib_func() {
      return 42;
    }
};

// Factory
Foo* create_foo() {
  return new Foo();
}
} // namespace Lib


/** I want to extend the 3rd party class, and only use
this extended class in my project */
class FooExtended : public Lib::Foo {
  public:
    float my_added_func() {
      return 1.0;
    }
};

/** Interface for class Foo, created so that a mock
implementation of `FooExtended` can be created for unit tests. */
class IFoo {
  public:
    virtual int lib_func() = 0;
    virtual float my_added_func() = 0;
};

/** Mock implemenation of IFoo for unit-tests. */
class FooMock : public IFoo() {
 // Blah blah
}

/** Non-mock implementation of IFoo. Just a wrapper for the class with the
actual implementation, i.e. FooExtended. */ 
class FooWrapper : public IFoo {
  public:
    int lib_func() override {
      assert(mFooExt);  // This fails because dynamic_cast failed.
      return mFooExt->lib_func();
    };

    float my_added_func() override {
      assert(mFooExt);  // This fails because dynamic_cast fails.
      return mFooExt->my_added_func();
    }

  private:
    unique_ptr<FooExtended> mFooExt {
      unique_ptr<FooExtended>(
        // This dynamic_cast fails.
        dynamic_cast<FooExtended*>(Lib::create_foo()))
    };
};

int main() {
  unique_ptr<IFoo> foo {  unique_ptr<IFoo>(new FooWrapper()) };
  assert(foo != nullptr);
  cout << "Starting...";
  // Exits the program because of the assert inside.
  cout << foo->lib_func() << "\n";
  cout << foo->my_added_func();
}
```

Comment: If instances of `Foo` have to be created via `Foo* create_foo()`, then you can't derive from `Foo`. The base class subobject of `FooExtended` obviously isn't, and can't be, created by `create_foo`. The best you can do is a class that holds a (possibly smart) pointer to `Foo` as a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not afraid to pay the price for calling virtual functions, you can create a wrapper for Foo and use it in your program:

```
class IFoo {
  public:
    virtual ~Foo() {};
    virtual int lib_func() = 0;
};

class MyFoo : public IFoo {
  int lib_func() override { _foo.lib_func(); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> _foo = create_foo(); // pseudocode
};
```

Now you can create mock and use it for IFoo.

Comment: Virtual function cost? You have measurment, in real code? You know better solution than table lookup?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right: in this case my extended functions should be added to the wrapper rather than in a derived class `FooExtended`.